# Activating a sheet in Google Apps Script doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have created a Google Apps Script that is [bound to a spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound). I am trying to programmatically change the active sheet to Sheet2 when a user clicks on a particular cell in Sheet1.

From the documentation, this should be simple; there is a Sheet method called [activate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#activate). However, calling this function via a trigger does not change the active sheet - Sheet1 stays in focus. Other functions like [hideSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidesheet) and [showSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#showsheet) work immediately, but not `activate()`.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Am I using this function incorrectly?

**EDIT**:
Here is the code that I am using:

```js
// I want to make my "Accounts" sheet the active sheet
function onSelectionChange(event) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Accounts")
  sheet.activate()
  // I tried flushing, waiting, and trying again; still doesn't work
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()
  Utilities.sleep(2000)
  sheet.activate()
  // However, hiding or showing the sheet works immediately:
  sheet.hideSheet()
}
```

Interestingly, on two occasions during troubleshooting, I have reopened the spreadsheet and this same code has *mysteriously started working*; however, on refreshing the page in Chrome, the `activate()` feature stops working again. This is what leads me to wonder if this may be an Apps Script bug.

Comment: @TheMaster - correct, this sheet is open in my browser. When running this function directly the code editor, both the activate() and hideSheet() functions succeed. However, when running this function using the onSelectionChange() trigger, only the hideSheet() function succeeds and the activate() function fails (most of the time...), as described above.

Comment: I just tested and it is working for me, have you tried to make a copy of the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

#### This works for me

```
function activateasheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").activate();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Utilities.sleep(5000);
  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").activate()
}
```

Comment: I tried this same code (I edited my original post above to show the code), and unfortunately this doesn't work for me when run via the onSelectionChange() trigger. Does it work for you when run via that trigger? Or only when running the function manually from the editor?

Comment: I just tested the code with  onSelectionChange and it worked for my but unfortunate it is not a good choice because the script keep generating onSelectionChange triggers which for a positive feedback loop and it nevers stops changing.

Comment: yep I won't leave the setup like this - I just want to get the code working and then I'll restrict the range of buttons that cause the sheet to hop to the next page.
Weird that it's working for you though. If you refresh the page, does it still work?